# Why does \centering causes a no-item-error when used as part of an argument?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, expl3

In the code below, I get some inut from a user, which includes commandssuch as `\\` and `\cntering`. The `\centering` and similar cause a no-item-error, although looking at the source2e I cannot spot the reason. Can you please advice how to modify this code so it work in all instances? I redefined `centering in the meantime and made it a no-op.

[image]

Usr adds items to a page by commands like \ADDLEFT, \ADDRIGHT etc. Then they added to the left or right based on some logic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,calc}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Store the user input
\dim_gzero_new:N \g_user_width_dim
\NewDocumentCommand\sometext{o +m}{
     \IfValueTF{#1}{
       \dim_gset:Nn \g_user_width_dim{#1}
     }{
        \dim_gset:Nn \g_user_width_dim{0pt}
     }
     
     \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
     
}

% Measure it
\NewDocumentCommand\measureit:N {+m} 

{
 
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box{ #1 }

 \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box {%
   
    \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
 }
} 




% Do some checks and render
\NewDocumentCommand\renderit { } 
{
 \tl_if_blank:oTF {\l_tmpa_tl} {}
 { 
  \measureit:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \dim_compare:nNnTF \g_user_width_dim>{0pt}{
     \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim \g_user_width_dim
  }{
     \dim_set:Nn\l_tmpa_dim{\box_wd:N\l_tmpb_box}
  } 
     \fbox{\parbox{\l_tmpa_dim   +30pt}  
     { 
           {\tl_use:N\l_tmpa_tl
          } 
      \par}
      }
}
 
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\let\ocentering\centering
\let\centering\undefined

\NewDocumentCommand\centering{}{ \ocentering}

\parindent0pt

\sometext{\centering This is a test\\ to see\\everything }
\renderit
\sometext{\centering  AAA\par BBB CCC \par}
\renderit
```

\end{document}

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you want to actually measure in that case.

Comment: \centering redefines ``\\``, and the replacement contains `\addvspace`, and that is something that you can't use in an \hbox. But as egreg says it is very unclear what you actually want to measure.

Comment: @egreg Thks user is providing some lines of text which includes commands like `\\` and ``\centering`` these are measured. The text is then put in a parbox at this width, after some checks. This is part of some much larger code base.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Thks the \addvspace was the cause. Changed from storing the text in a \tl to a \seq and is not issuing the error now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry error still occuring, pls ignore my previous comment